# Is it possible to use OR condition/operator in replace function?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace

I have simple String program in Java. I need to use replace() function. In which, I have to replace few words with the help of OR condition if they occur in the given String.

```
e.g. String s = "I am a boy";
s = s.replace("I", "something"); //works ok
s = s.replace("I | am", "something"); //wants to do it
System.out.println(s);
```

I know programatically by coding own it is possible but just thought to place question here before going to final way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `replaceAll` to use a regular expression.

Comment: Why don't you just perform two replacements ?

Comment: Thank you for comments. Will try

Answer (score 5):

Use `replaceAll`/`replaceFirst` which allows you to use regex statements to match the fragments you want to replace.

```
String result "I am I am a boy".replaceAll("I|am", "something");
// result = "something something something something a boy"
```

or

```
String result = "I am I am a boy".replaceFirst("I|am", "something");
// result = "something am I am a boy"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will try

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
s = s.replace(/(I|am)/g, "something");
```

The replace function either searches for the text or a regular expression, for two or more words regular expression can be used. In this way you can use to replace multiple words in a string.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will try

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion